# if counter is >9 then i want to print a letter equal to the counter in letter

Tags: c++

I am making a nonogram but one requirement is that when a counter is bigger then 9 I want te print letters instead, so for example if the counter is 10 I want to print an A, 11-B, etc. this is the function I have, the value hulp is put in an array in a different function.

```
int nono::letter(int counter){
    char hulp;
     if (counter > 9){
        return hulp ='a'+counter;
     }
}
```

the function I put it in:

```
void nono::makeDis (){
    bool empty = false;
    int Dis;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= width; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++){
            column[j][i] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= width; j++){
        besc = 0;
        counter=0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++){
            if (denono[i][j]==1){
                counter++;
            }else if(counter > 0 && counter <10){
                column[j][besc]=counter;
                besc++;
                counter = 0;
            }else if(counter>9){
                column[j][besc]=letter(counter);
                besc++;
                counter=0;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and this is how I print the array:

```
void nono::printDescColumn(){
    bool notEmpty;
    int x =0;
    
    cout << "   ";
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        controlBeschKolom(j);
        if(valideK[j]) {
            cout << "V ";
        }
        else{
            cout << "  ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        notEmpty=false;
        cout<< "   ";
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            ///controlBeschKolom(j);
            if(column[j][i]!=0 ){
                cout<<column[j][i]<<" ";
                notEmpty=true;
            }else{
                cout<<"  ";
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
        if(!notEmpty){
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

[What I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02Fnn.png)
so instead of 75 I want an A

Comment: It looks like `colom[j][besc]` constrains either a number or (the code of) a character. This looks dangerously hard to use later on. Why aren't you converting small numbers like `5` into their corresponding characters `'5'` ? Or, maybe, you need that to store the plain number, and only switch to the letters later on, at print-time. I can't understand the logic of your code.

Comment: It's useless to assign a variable just for return : `return hulp ='a'+counter;` ... You can return `a'+counter` directly

Comment: fwiw you don't have to repost questions. You could have edited the old one.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. What is `colom` ? Where is it declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to first subtract 10 from the counter before adding it to 'a' to make sure you are using the correct offset. and since you are already checking if the number us above 9 in the calling code, you don't need to do it here. So your code simplifies to the following:

```
char nono::letter(int counter){
   return 'A'+counter-10;   
}
```

And also in the print function, make sure to convert the column array values to char before printing them like so:

```
void nono::printDescColumn(){
bool notEmpty;
int x =0;

cout << "   ";
for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    controlBeschKolom(j);
    if(valideK[j]) {
        cout << "V ";
    }
    else{
        cout << "  ";
    }
}
cout << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
    notEmpty=false;
    cout<< "   ";
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){
        ///controlBeschKolom(j);
        if(column[j][i]!=0 ){
            if(column[j[[i]>9) {
                cout<<char(column[j][i]<<" ";
            }else{
                cout<<column[j][i]<<" ";
            }
            notEmpty=true;
        }else{
            cout<<"  ";
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
    if(!notEmpty){
        break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: This still gives me 65 instead of A

Comment: have you changed the return type from int to char. your code says

int nono::letter(int counter){...

needs to be 

char nono::letter(int counter){...

Comment: This is wrong: imagine that `counter` is 8, then this returns ASCII(63), which is not the character "8" but "?" (the question mark).

Comment: Yes, I did that

Comment: Yes, but in the code he's only calling the function if the counter is > 9. so there is no chance of that happening

Comment: "above" depends on each users sorting. There is no answer above yours in my view

Comment: Consider that if `column` stores `int`s then both answers won't make OPs code print letters. We cannot know from what OP did post, but it is rather likely, because they do assign `int`s to it

Comment: new here. sorry.

Comment: and for the question i think the problem is with the container. i think the column array is an int and casting your char's to int when you insert them to it. that's why you are getting int values when you print.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of that `hulp` variable is obsolete and makes your code look suspicious. Why don't you do it as follows:

```
char nono::letter(int counter){
     if (counter > 9){
        return 'A'+counter;
     }
     else return '0' + counter;
}
```

In top of this, you mention what you want to see, you show the program you have created until now, but when you run that program, what do you actually see? (This might help us understanding where you have your problem (and what problem by the way?))

Comment: what if `column` stores `int`s not `char`s ? Then this change won't make OPs code print letters

Comment: @idclev463035818: `int` and `char` are easily inversable: 65 is understood as the same as the letter 'A'. Obviously, you need to make sure to be syntactically correct.

Comment: I know that, but apparently OP not, the whole question is about how to print some integers as letters